# Find the interior, closure and more of the following set

Tags: real-analysis, metric-spaces

Let

${A_1} = \left\{ {\left( {m,n} \right) \in {\mathbb{R}^2}|{m^2} + {n^2} \leqslant 1} \right\}$

${A_2} = \left\{ {\left( {m,n} \right) \in {\mathbb{R}^2}|0 \leqslant m < 1,n = 0} \right\}$

${A_3} = \left\{ {\left( {m,n} \right) \in {\mathbb{R}^2}|m = 1,n \in \mathbb{R}} \right\}$

$M = \left( {{A_1} \cup {A_3}} \right)\backslash {A_2}$

So my progress so far is:

Closure of M is ${A_1} \cup {A_3}$

Interior of M is $\left\{ {\left( {m,n} \right) \in {\mathbb{R}^2}|{m^2} + {n^2} < 1,} \right\}\backslash {A_2}$.

Boundary of M is $\left\{ {\left( {m,n} \right) \in {\mathbb{R}^2}|{m^2} + {n^2} = 1,} \right\}$.

Interior of closure of M is essentially the interior of M.

Closure of interior of M is ${A_1} \cup {A_3}$.

I am not sure if I got it all correct so please help enlighten me.

Thank you all.

Comment: It might not be a bad idea to write what $M$ is in set notation.  And it really could help if you try to answer whether $M$ is open, closed, both or neither first.

Comment: @fleablood I can only visualize it as a circle with the tangent line at x=1 and without half of the line that contains the origin.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a ball. In that ball you remove a line with origin in the center of the ball. To the boundary you add another line as a tangent vector.
Therefore your closure is right.
Interior also right.
For the boundary check your definition.
The set $A_3$ is also contained. 
The interior of the closure is not always the interior again. In your case, your closure is a full ball with straight line attached, therefore the ball without boundary is the interior of the closure. Closure of interior is also wrong.
It‘s the full ball.

Comment: Thanks so much. I almost figured it out. Also for the boundary, I agree it's the boundary of the circle and $A_{3}$. Should it also contain the line with the origin?

Comment: @lalaland4545 The line through the origin is $A_2$. If you draw a ball around any point of the line, a point of the ball is contained, therefore it‘s in the closure as well.

Comment: so the boundary should contain the boundary of the circle, $A_{2}$ and $A_{3}$. Am I correct?

Comment: @lalaland4545 That‘s correct! Have fun with topology :)